# Font conversion Kurtidev to mangal

Tags: c#, fonts, asp.net-web-api

I have a microsoft access file in which data is stored in kurtidev font. I have to convert it in to Mangal font. Is there any api available (Free) to do so? If not please suggest the ways to do it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Kruti Dev, these fonts use Latin/English Unicodes [(U+0000 range)](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf) to encode Devanagari glyph shapes. Mangal, on the other hand, correctly uses Unicodes from the Devanagari range [(U+0900)](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0900.pdf). In other words, Devanagari 'Ka' (क), U+0915 in Mangal, is instead assigned to U+0064 in Kruti Dev. U+0064 is supposed to be Latin 'd'.

To get your database contents to display correctly with Mangal, you'll need to perform a transformation on the text from "Devanagari-as-Latin" Unicode into Devanagari Unicodes. That will require some sort of translation table.

A search for ['kruti dev to unicode converter'](https://www.google.com/search?&q=kruti%20dev%20to%20unicode%20converter) turns up a number of tools, some free, some for cost. There's even an [online version](http://www.rcvponline.com/fontconverter.aspx). I was unable to find any source code for these tools which will likely contain the translation table that you need but you may be able to find something. Or you might be able to derive your own table by running a full complement of Kruti-encoded text through a converter and examining the output.